# Install Go CLI application without having Go installed

Tags: go, download, installation, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

If I already have Go installed on my computer, I can easily install a CLI application using this [github repository](https://github.com/codegangsta/cli).  I need to install a CLi application on a machine that does not have Go installed (like the CloudFoundry CLI) - how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Go compiles to one executable, the end user does not need go installed.

Comment: Yes..but if I need to access the CLI tool from anywhere in the system, I cannot be using the executable right? Because to run the executable I should be in the path of the executable.

Comment: Yes. You should put the binary somewhere that is in your PATH. Probably something like `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Yeah what @cpjolicoeur said. If you're on windows just go to System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > PATH and add ";C:\path\to\your\file\mycli.exe" then just open up a command pompt and type mycli

Answer (score 0):

You could try a newly released tool like [goget.sh](https://github.com/soheilhy/goget)

Comment: Looks like this tool can be useful. Thanks